# math in horseshoe puzzle

Tags: puzzle, knot-theory

We know that Rubik's Cube is a good demonstration of group theory. Correspondingly, for the [horseshoe puzzle](http://waynesword.palomar.edu/trjuly98.htm) as in the picture below, is there a math language for it? Does it demonstrate any math subject?

[image],

Comment: Likely *topology* but I wouldn't have the first clue how to describe it in those terms!

Comment: had you heard about *isotopy*?

Answer (score 2):

Such puzzles typically are related mainly with knot theory.